# PHP variable not updating in to MYSQl field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a piece of code which takes the keywords out of a url from a database.  The code then updates a field within the database with the keywords.  The code gets the keywords from the url successfully and then echo's them out on to the page perfectly.

However when I try and update them in to the database, the field doesn't update.  If i swap out the variable $c for a word such as test this works perfectly and so the issue is with the variable $c, however i have tried to do this several different ways but i just can not get the field to update.

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_stats1 WHERE page LIKE   'http://www.google.com/uds/afs?q=%' AND id='44'")
 or die(mysql_error());  
 $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );


 $keyword = $row['page'];   
 $id = $row['id'];

 $a = "$keyword"; 
 $b = substr($a, strpos($a, '=') + 1); 
 print $b; 
 $c = substr($b, 0, strpos($b, '$')); 
 echo "$c";

 $result2 = mysql_query("UPDATE ip_stats1 SET string1 = '$c' WHERE id = '44'") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

UPDATE

ok, so if I echo $c i get the keywords, so it would simply be for example something like  Dough Maker, so that works perfectly.   i have also tried writing it like this.

```
 $test = $c;
```

and then test returns the same result.  Originally this was a loop and i took all of the results fro the database to produce a long list, but in an effort to try and find the error i removed the loop to just return one result.

Comment: What does `echo $c` show?

Comment: Are you getting any error from `die(mysql_error())`? Try printing the query with the variable substituted, and then executing that query by hand.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array return array, you use $row['page'] is error

Comment: @tungbk29 What's wrong with it? It returns an array containing both numeric and associative indexes. You're confusing it with `mysql_fetch_row()`, which just returns numeric indexes.

Comment: I think mysql_fetch_array return array and you should use loop(while) for return value $row['page'];

Comment: Originally i was printing the error, but i had the same problem, so i just changed to echo as a process of ilimination, but i don't get any errors reportes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, firstly thanks for all your suggestions, I tried various things and then in the end simply realised that actually this was a silly error.  the variable $b holds the information i want and  as soon as i inserted this to the database everything worked fine.